# spyOn is not called even though it passed through the function

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I created a test for my `ngOnChanges` but even though it passed through the function,
there's an error

`Error: Expected spy selectItem to have been called.`

Here is my ngOnChange

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        const eventDataChange: SimpleChange = changes['selectEventData'];

        if (eventDataChange) {
            this.selectItem(eventDataChange.currentValue);
        }
    }
```

Here is the unit test:

```
describe('ngOnChange()', () => {
        it('this is a description', () => {
            const selectDto = 'test';
            const eventDataChange: SimpleChange = new SimpleChange(null, selectDto, false);
            const simpleChanges: SimpleChanges = {
                selectEventData: eventDataChange
            };

            component.ngOnChanges(simpleChanges);

            const selectSpy = spyOn(component, 'selectItem');

            expect(selectSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
```

Hoping for a kind response!

Thank you!

Comment: How do you create a test component?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav I created an object with mock functions. component = new DropDownComponent(mock, mock, mock);

Comment: I guess it's because you've added the spy after `ngOnChanges()` call, try to add it before the call

Comment: what a stupid and careless mistake. -_- thanks @ValeriyKatkov

Comment: That's why I asked the code of initialization of the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spyOn` spies only calls that come after the spy is registered. In your example `spyOn()` is executed after `ngOnChanges()` is called, it's the problem. Just move `spyOn()` call before the `ngOnChanges()` call:

```js
const selectSpy = spyOn(component, 'selectItem');
component.ngOnChanges(simpleChanges);
expect(selectSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```